# BitmapFactory.decodeFile() returning null value

Tags: android, imageview, bitmapfactory

In my application i am select image from the gallery and setting it to the image view.The problem is that the image is not being displayed in the image view.I had debugged but app for the prob,so i found that the method BitmapFactory.decodeFile("image path") is returning null value even thought the path which i am getting is totally fine.

Code

```
case R.id.imageView:

                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_CODE);

                break;

if (requestCode == GALLERY_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            ivImage.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
    }
```

I dont know why this is happening.
Please do help me out

Comment: did you check value of 'picturePath' using debug mode

Comment: Ya i am getting the path of the picture

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442316/bitmap-is-returning-null-from-bitmapfactory-decodefilefilename

Answer (score 0):

Did you give the permission like these in yours **manifest file** below minSdk and maxSdk

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i solved the problem by giving these permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```