# BitmapFactory.decodeFile is null

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I tried several ways but it always returns 'null'.

I want to read a file from the camera folder into a bitmap object.

```
File camDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/DCIM/Camera");
    File[] files = camDir.listFiles();
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[1].getAbsolutePath());
    img.getDensity();
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Maybe it is long because the image is too large, can you put a try catch and get the exception?

Comment: You are assuming that `files[1]` is going to point to a bitmap. Also, this will only work if you have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, and depending upon your device OS version and `targetSdkVersion`, you may need to request that permission from the user at runtime.

Comment: Why you don't use this? : `File camDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera");`

Comment: @Skizo The try/catch don't catching it and maybe it is to large because it is about 3-4MB

Comment: @CommonsWare I have all the permissions that need, nad I just want to get one file from the camera folder

Comment: @SimonDzn test my answer, let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what's the `null` you can add a simple `try()catch(Exception e)` and then `e.printstacktrace();` to get the error.

If the error is about `outOfMemory` try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8442683/4385913);

Also, you may try this trick :

```
File camDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/DCIM/Camera");
File[] files = camDir.listFiles();
FileInputStream FI = new FileInputStream (files[1].getAbsolutePath());
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FI);
img.getDensity();
```

Another try that I mentioned to you on comments you can remove the `getAbsolutePath()` and do it as follows :

```
File camDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the help!!

I found that the problem was the "getAbsolutePath()" I don't understand why but it works..

I changed this:

```
File camDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/DCIM/Camera");
```

To:

```
File camDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera");
```

And it works!