# BitmapFactory.decodeFile() returns null in some devices

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory, image-compression

I'm using following code from [here](http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/). I want to compress image.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
```

After choose image from Camera, Gallery and Photos, i'm getting different type of paths in different devices based on OS type and device model. like:

1) /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/...

2) /raw//storage/emulated/0/mb/1511172993547.jpg

3) /2/1/content://media/external/images/media/11647/ORIGINAL/NONE/486073582

If path is like 1st url, this code is working fine. But if i get other types of images, then BitmapFactory.decodeFile() is giving null.

Is there any way to compress image in all types of devices and OS versions.

**UPDATE :**

To Open Picker :

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
pickIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 1001);
```

After choosing image :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(data.getData().getPath()));
    Bitmap cmpBitmap = ImageUtils.compressUriQuality(OpenWallWeb.this, imgUri);
    dlgImageToPost.setImageBitmap(cmpBitmap);
...
}
```

For compression :

```
public static Bitmap compressUriQuality(Context mContext, Uri selectedImage) {
    InputStream imageStream = null;
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {
        imageStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                selectedImage);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);

        if (imageStream != null)
            imageStream.close();
        stream.close();
        stream = null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: you have image `Uri`, so open its `InputStream` and decode it using `BitmapFactory` - you can get `InputStream` by using `ContentResolver` API

Comment: are you trying to get image path from galley or any other path ???

Comment: and no, do not use any "image path" - all you need is `Uri`

Comment: Thank you for commenting, i'll try using Uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tv      2) /raw//storage/emulated/0/mb/1511172993547.jpg

That is not a path you would get if the user selected pictures from Gallery or Photos. And certainly it is no file system path you could use for .decodeFile(). How did you obtain it?

```
3) /2/1/content://media/external/images/media/11647/ORIGINAL/NONE/486073582
```

That is no valid content scheme path. How did you obtain it? And certainly cannot be used for .decodeFile().

```
  i'm getting different type of paths
```

You will never get such paths if you 'act normal'. So what is it what you are doing? Elementary uri handling wrong?

```
using following code from here.
```

That is pretty dirty example code for a big part as you have perceived now.

```
any way to compress image in all types of devices and OS versions.
```

Of course. Just use the obtained selected uri directly. Open an InputStream for it and use .decodeStream() instead.

My god.. you are not using the uri directly.

```
 Bitmap cmpBitmap = ImageUtils.compressUriQuality(OpenWallWeb.this, imgUri);
```

Change to

```
  Bitmap cmpBitmap = ImageUtils.compressUriQuality(OpenWallWeb.this, data.getData());
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, i'll try to use Url

Comment: Error coming on using Uri also, when i choose image from photos in Xiomi, data.getData().getPath() returns url like '/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/7741/ORIGINAL/NONE/1544403096'. In this case, mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri) is giving FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Please show complete code. Put the code in your post. Not in a comment. Unreadable. Also post complete exception message from logcat. IN YOUR POST.

Comment: The content scheme is in data.getData().toString(). Dont use getPath().

Comment: Also show with which intent you obtained the uri. You did not answer: `How did you obtain it?`.

Comment: I updated code, i also tried with data.getData().toString() but that also returns same exception.

Comment: You should not try uri.toString() you should use the uri directly. See my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, please add storage permission to your app.

Check this link for more info

[Storage permission error in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)