# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress on a null object reference

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap, bytearrayoutputstream

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
The line which causes the error is original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

public class MenuScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

         dbName1 = Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                    MenuScreen.this, "DataBaseName");


        urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("UserID=");
        urlString.append(Preferences.getintegerPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                "UserId"));
        urlString.append("&DbName=");
        urlString.append(Preferences.getStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                "DataBaseName"));

        if (cw == null)
            cw = new ConnectToWebService(MenuScreen.this);

        getMethod gmLastPunch = getMethod.GetLastPunchInByID;
        String url = cw.getUrl(urlString.toString(), gmLastPunch).replaceAll(
                " ", "%20");
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MenuScreen.this, "",
                "In Process. Please wait...", false);
        new AsyncGetLastPunchIn().execute(url);


        if (SerializationUtil.MachinesPermission == null)
            SerializationUtil.deserialize(MenuScreen.this);


        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Logout)).setOnClickListener(this);

        thread = new ProcessThreadUploadImage();
        thread.start();

     final Handler handler = new Handler();
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             CheckPendingImages();
             handler.postDelayed(this, 2000); 
         }
      }, 2000);
    }
public void CheckPendingImages() {

        File file = new File(root.getPath());
        String[] names = file.list();
        if(names!=null)
        {
        for(String name1 : names)
        {
         dbName1 = Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                    MenuScreen.this, "DataBaseName");

            if(name1.equals(dbName1))
            {
            File file1=new File(root.getPath() +"/"+ name1);
            if (file1.isDirectory())
            {
                  File[] image = file1.listFiles(); 
                  if(image.length!=0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
                        if (!(image[i].getName()).equals((i + 1) + ".jpeg")) {
                            count1=image.length;
                    }
                    }
            }
        }               
        }
        }
        }

        File file2 = new File(root1.getPath());
        String[] names2 = file2.list();
        if(names2!=null)
        {
        for(String name3 : names2)
        {
            if(name3.equals(dbName1))
            {
            File file3=new File(root1.getPath() +"/"+ name3);
            if (file3.isDirectory())
            {
                  File[] image = file3.listFiles(); 
                  if(image.length!=0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
                            if (!(image[i].getName()).equals((i + 1) + ".jpeg")) {
                                count2=image.length;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            }
        }
        }
        count=count1+count2;
        Pendingimage.setText("Pending Uploads: "+count);            
    }   

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {    

            case R.id.btn_Logout:

                Intent logout = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);

                startActivity(logout);

                break;   

        }    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_punchin);
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            String DatabaseName=Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                    MenuScreen.this, "DataBaseName");
            String PunchID=Preferences.getStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this, "PunchID");
                 bundle = new Bundle();

            Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, ShowDbList.class);
             punch = menu.getItem(0);
                if ((punch
                        .getIcon()
                        .getConstantState()
                        .equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green)
                                .getConstantState()) || Preferences
                        .getBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this, "IsPunchIn"))) {
                bundle.putString("DatabaseName", DatabaseName);
                bundle.putString("PunchID", PunchID);

                  upIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                }

            startActivity(upIntent);                

        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_punchin) {
            item1.setEnabled(false);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, GPSTrackerNew.class);
            Intent LocUploadIntent = new Intent(this, GPSLocationUpload.class);
            if ((item
                    .getIcon()
                    .getConstantState()
                    .equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red)
                            .getConstantState()) || !Preferences
                    .getBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this, "IsPunchIn"))) {
                Preferences.saveBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                        "IsPunchIn", true);
                if (Integer.parseInt(Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                        MenuScreen.this, "LocationTrackOption")) == 3) {
                    startService(myIntent);


                    startService(LocUploadIntent);
                }
            } 

            thread = new processThreadServerTime();
            thread.start();             

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class processThreadGetLastPunchIn extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            urlString = new StringBuilder();
            urlString.append("UserID=");
            urlString.append(Preferences.getintegerPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                    "UserId"));
            urlString.append("&DbName=");
            urlString.append(Preferences.getStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                    "DataBaseName"));

            if (cw == null)
                cw = new ConnectToWebService(MenuScreen.this);

            getMethod gmLastPunch = getMethod.GetLastPunchInByID;
            String url = cw.getUrl(urlString.toString(), gmLastPunch)
                    .replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            resultPunchIn = cw.callWebService(url);

            handlerLastPunchIn.sendEmptyMessage(0);    
        }
    }

    public class processThreadServerTime extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            if (cw == null)
                cw = new ConnectToWebService(MenuScreen.this);

            getMethod gm = getMethod.GetApplicationDetails;
            String urlLogoutTime = cw.getUrl("", gm).replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            dateTime = cw.UpdateVersion(urlLogoutTime);

            handlerServerTime.sendEmptyMessage(0);

        }
    }
    public class processThreadServerTime1 extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            if (cw == null)
                cw = new ConnectToWebService(MenuScreen.this);

            getMethod gm = getMethod.GetApplicationDetails;
            String urlLogoutTime = cw.getUrl("", gm).replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            dateTime = cw.UpdateVersion(urlLogoutTime);

            handlerServerTime1.sendEmptyMessage(0);

        }
    }
    final Handler handlerLastPunchIn = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            super.handleMessage(msg);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resultPunchIn);
                JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("punchList");
                if (jsonArr.length() > 0) {
                    String punchout = jsonArr.getJSONObject(0).getString(
                            "PunchOutTime");
                    Preferences.saveStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                            "PunchId",
                            jsonArr.getJSONObject(0).getString("PunchID"));
                    String str = Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                            MenuScreen.this, "PunchID");
                    if (punchout == "null")
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.greenpunch, menu);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {    

            }

        }
    };
    final Handler handlerServerTime = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            super.handleMessage(msg);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(dateTime);
                Preferences.saveStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                        "LoginOutTime", jsonObject.getString("DateTimeNow"));

                callPunchInOutAPI();
            } catch (JSONException e) {    

            }    
        }
    };
    final Handler handlerServerTime1 = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            super.handleMessage(msg);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(dateTime);
                Preferences.saveStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                        "LoginOutTime", jsonObject.getString("DateTimeNow"));

                callAutomaticPunchInOutAPI();
            } catch (JSONException e) {


            }    
        }
    };
    public void callPunchInOutAPI() {

        getMethod gm;
        String punchTime = GetImageDateTime();
        double strLatitude;
        double strLongitude;

        Location location = null;
        if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {
            gpsTracker.getLocation(this);
            location = gpsTracker._location;
        }

        if (location != null) {
            strLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            strLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        } 

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        if (Preferences.getBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this, "IsPunchIn")) {
            =
            String serverTime = Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                    MenuScreen.this, "LoginOutTime");
            serverTime1=Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                    MenuScreen.this, "LoginOutTime");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            String deviceTime = df.format(c.getTime());
            try {

                Date oldDate = (Date) oldFormatter.parse(Preferences
                        .getStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this, "LoginOutTime"));
                serverTime = newFormatter.format(oldDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            jsonObjectPunchInData = new JSONObject();
            try {

                jsonObjectPunchInData.put("UserID", Preferences
                        .getintegerPreferences(MenuScreen.this, "UserId"));
                urlString = new StringBuilder();
                urlString.append("DbName=");
                urlString.append(Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                        MenuScreen.this, "DataBaseName"));
                gm = getMethod.InsertPunchInData;

                new AsyncInsertPunchInOutData().execute(cw.getUrl(
                        urlString.toString(), gm).replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
            }    
            catch (Exception ex) {
                if (dialog != null)
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }           
            }           

    }

    public void callAutomaticPunchInOutAPI() {

        getMethod gm = null;
        String punchTime = GetImageDateTime();
        double strLatitude;
        double strLongitude;

        Location location = null;
        if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {
            gpsTracker.getLocation(this);
            location = gpsTracker._location;
        }

        if (location != null) {
            strLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            strLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        }       

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle!=null)
{
    Boolean punchstatus=bundle.getBoolean("punchstatus");
    String PunchedInDatabase=bundle.getString("PunchedInDatabase");
    String DatabaseName=bundle.getString("DatabaseName");
    String previousdatabasename=bundle.getString("previousdatabasename");
    String PunchID=bundle.getString("PunchID");
    if(previousdatabasename!=null)
    {
    jsonObjectPunchInData = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObjectPunchInData.put("PunchID", PunchID);
        jsonObjectPunchInData.put("PunchedOutDatabase", previousdatabasename);
        jsonObjectPunchInData.put("PunchedInUserID", Preferences
                .getintegerPreferences(MenuScreen.this, "UserId"));
        jsonObjectPunchInData.put("PunchedInDatabase", DatabaseName);
        jsonObjectPunchInData.put("PunchOutTime", punchTime);
        jsonObjectPunchInData.put("PunchOutLatitude", strLatitude);
        jsonObjectPunchInData.put("PunchOutLongitude", strLongitude); 

        urlString = new StringBuilder();

        gm = getMethod.UpdatePunchStatusForUser;    
            }

    catch (Exception ex) {
        if (dialog != null)
            dialog.dismiss();
    }
}       
}
    new AsyncInsertPunchInOutData1().execute(cw.getUrl(
            urlString.toString(), gm).replaceAll(" ", "%20"));


    }
        public class AsyncGetLastPunchIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String output;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            output = cw.callWebService(arg0[0]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dismissProgressDialog();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(output);
                JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("punchList");
                if (jsonArr.length() > 0) {
                    String punchout = jsonArr.getJSONObject(0).getString(
                            "PunchOutTime");

                    Preferences.saveStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                            "PunchID",
                            jsonArr.getJSONObject(0).getString("PunchID"));

                    if (punchout == "null") {
                        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.greenpunch, menu);
                        Preferences.saveBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                                "IsPunchIn", true);
                        if (Integer.parseInt(Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                                MenuScreen.this, "LocationTrackOption")) == 3)
                            startService(myIntent);
                    } else {
                        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.punch, menu);
                        Preferences.saveBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                                "IsPunchIn", false);
                        if (Integer.parseInt(Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                                MenuScreen.this, "LocationTrackOption")) == 3) {
                            stopService(myIntent);
                            gpsTracker.stopRunnable();
                        }
                    }
                } 
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
            CheckMenu();
        }    
    }

    public class AsyncInsertPunchInOutData extends
            AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if (Preferences.getBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this, "IsPunchIn")) {
                return cw.postData(params[0], jsonObjectPunchInData);
            } 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (dialog != null)
                dialog.dismiss();
            if (Preferences.getBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this, "IsPunchIn")) {
                try {    
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    String InsertPunchIn = jsonObject
                            .getString("InsertPunchInDataResult");

                    if (Integer.parseInt(InsertPunchIn) != 0) {
                        Preferences.saveBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                                "IsPunchIn", true);

                        Preferences.saveStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                                "PunchID", InsertPunchIn);

                        MenuItem punch = menu.getItem(0);
                        punch.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.green));
                        Preferences.saveStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                                "punch", punch.toString());

                        Preferences.saveStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                                "PunchTime", serverTime1);



                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {                     

                }
            }    
        }    
    }

    public class AsyncInsertPunchInOutData1 extends
    AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {    
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (dialog != null)
        dialog.dismiss();

        try {    
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String InsertPunchIn = jsonObject
                    .getString("UpdatePunchStatusForUserResult");

            if (Integer.parseInt(InsertPunchIn) != 0) {
                Preferences.saveBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                        "IsPunchIn", true);

                Preferences.saveStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                        "PunchID", InsertPunchIn);                  

                MenuItem punch = menu.getItem(0);
                punch.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.green));
                Preferences.saveStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                        "punch", punch.toString());

                Preferences.saveStringPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                        "PunchTime", serverTime1);      

            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }

}    
}       

    private String GetImageDateTime() {
        String returnVal = "";
        try {


            String dateInString = Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                    MenuScreen.this, "LoginOutTime");

            Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);

                        System.out.println("Date : " + formatter.format(date));


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnVal;
    }    

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (cw == null)
            cw = new ConnectToWebService(MenuScreen.this);

        new AsyncLogout(this).execute();            

    }

    private void dismissProgressDialog() {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        dismissProgressDialog();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
     public void CheckMenu(){

         Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(bundle!=null)
            {
            Boolean punchstatus=bundle.getBoolean("punchstatus");
            String PunchedInDatabase=bundle.getString("PunchedInDatabase");
            String DatabaseName=bundle.getString("DatabaseName");
            String previousdatabasename=bundle.getString("previousdatabasename");
            String PunchID=bundle.getString("PunchID");
            if(previousdatabasename!=null)
            {
            if(!DatabaseName.equals(previousdatabasename))
            {

            punch = menu.getItem(0);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, GPSTrackerNew.class);
            Intent LocUploadIntent = new Intent(this, GPSLocationUpload.class);
            if ((punch
                    .getIcon()
                    .getConstantState()
                    .equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red)
                            .getConstantState()) || !Preferences
                    .getBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this, "IsPunchIn"))) {
                Preferences.saveBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                        "IsPunchIn", true);
                if (Integer.parseInt(Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                        MenuScreen.this, "LocationTrackOption")) == 3) {
                    startService(myIntent);
                                        startService(LocUploadIntent);
                }
            }

            thread = new processThreadServerTime1();
            thread.start();
            }
            }
            else if(punchstatus==true && !dbName1.equals(PunchedInDatabase))
         {

                 punch = menu.getItem(0);
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, GPSTrackerNew.class);
                    Intent LocUploadIntent = new Intent(this, GPSLocationUpload.class);
                    if ((punch
                            .getIcon()
                            .getConstantState()
                            .equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red)
                                    .getConstantState()) || !Preferences
                            .getBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this, "IsPunchIn"))) {
                        Preferences.saveBooleanPreferences(MenuScreen.this,
                                "IsPunchIn", true);
                        if (Integer.parseInt(Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                                MenuScreen.this, "LocationTrackOption")) == 3) {
                            startService(myIntent);

                            startService(LocUploadIntent);
                        }
                    } 

                    thread = new processThreadServerTime1();
                    thread.start();                                 
     }       
            }
     }
     public class ProcessThreadUploadImage extends Thread 
        {           
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();

                File[] image = root3.listFiles();
                File[] image1 = root4.listFiles();
                if(image!=null)
                {
                String[] imgName = root3.list();

                String DBName = Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                        MenuScreen.this, "DataBaseName");
                for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
                    if (!(image[i].getName()).equals((i + 1) + ".jpeg")) {                           

                        Bitmap  original = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image[i].getPath());
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                        Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
                        byte[] b1 = out.toByteArray();
                        String bitmapstring1 = Base64.encodeToString(b1,Base64.DEFAULT);
                        jsonuploadimage = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            jsonuploadimage.put("FileData",bitmapstring1);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            jsonuploadimage.put("name",imgName[i]);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                         StringBuffer urlString=new StringBuffer(); 
                         urlString.append("&DbName=");
                            urlString.append(DBName);

                            if (cw == null)
                                cw = new ConnectToWebService(
                                        MenuScreen.this);

                            getMethod gm = getMethod.uploadImages;

                                thread = new ProcessThreadUploadImage2(cw
                                        .getUrl(urlString.toString(), gm)
                                        .replaceAll(" ", "%20"),
                                        jsonuploadimage);
                                thread.start();
                                 try {
                                    thread.join();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                }
                }
                                }
                if(image1!=null)
                {
                    String[] imgName1 = root4.list();
                    String DBName = Preferences.getStringPreferences(
                            MenuScreen.this, "DataBaseName");
                    for (int i = 0; i < image1.length; i++) {
                        if (!(image1[i].getName()).equals((i + 1) + ".jpeg")) { 
                            Bitmap  original = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image1[i].getPath());
                            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                            Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
                            byte[] b1 = out.toByteArray();
                            String bitmapstring1 = Base64.encodeToString(b1,Base64.DEFAULT);
                            jsonuploadimage = new JSONObject();
                            try {
                                jsonuploadimage.put("FileData",bitmapstring1);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                            try {
                                jsonuploadimage.put("name",imgName1[i]);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                             StringBuffer urlString=new StringBuffer(); 
                             urlString.append("&DbName=");
                                urlString.append(DBName);

                                if (cw == null)
                                    cw = new ConnectToWebService(
                                            MenuScreen.this);

                                getMethod gm = getMethod.uploadImages;
                                                                        thread = new ProcessThreadUploadImage3(cw
                                            .getUrl(urlString.toString(), gm)
                                            .replaceAll(" ", "%20"),
                                            jsonuploadimage);
                                    thread.start();
                                     try {
                                        thread.join();
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                    }}  }   }
            }           

        public class ProcessThreadUploadImage2 extends Thread {

            String urlPostData2;
            JSONObject Jsonuploadimage;

            public ProcessThreadUploadImage2(String urlPostData2,
                    JSONObject jsonuploadimage) {
                super();
                this.urlPostData2 = urlPostData2;
                Jsonuploadimage = jsonuploadimage;
            }    
            @Override
            public void run() {

                super.run();
                if (cw == null)
                    cw = new ConnectToWebService(MenuScreen.this);
                try {
                    filename= Jsonuploadimage.getString("name");
                } catch (JSONException e1) {


                }
            statusImageUpload = cw.postData(urlPostData2, Jsonuploadimage);
            checkStatus();

            }    
        }
        public void checkStatus()
        {
        String ImageUploadResult = null;

            if (statusImageUpload != null) {
                try {
                    jsonuploadimage = new JSONObject(statusImageUpload);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    ImageUploadResult = jsonuploadimage
                            .getString("uploadImagesResult");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (ImageUploadResult != null) {
                    ImageUploadResult2 = Integer
                            .parseInt(ImageUploadResult);

                if(ImageUploadResult2==1)
                {
                    File file = new File(root3.getPath()+"/"+ filename);
                    file.delete();
                }
            }
            }
        }
        public class ProcessThreadUploadImage3 extends Thread {

            String urlPostData3;
            JSONObject Jsonuploadimage3;

            public ProcessThreadUploadImage3(String urlPostData3,
                    JSONObject jsonuploadimage3) {
                super();
                            this.urlPostData3 = urlPostData3;
                Jsonuploadimage3 = jsonuploadimage3;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                if (cw == null)
                    cw = new ConnectToWebService(MenuScreen.this);
                try {
                    filename= Jsonuploadimage3.getString("name");
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }               
                statusImageUpload = cw.postData(urlPostData3, Jsonuploadimage3);
            checkStatus3();

            }

        }
        public void checkStatus3()
        {
        String ImageUploadResult = null;

            if (statusImageUpload != null) {
                try {
                    jsonuploadimage = new JSONObject(statusImageUpload);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    ImageUploadResult = jsonuploadimage
                            .getString("uploadImagesResult");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (ImageUploadResult != null) {
                    ImageUploadResult2 = Integer
                            .parseInt(ImageUploadResult);

                if(ImageUploadResult2==1)
                {
                    File file = new File(root4.getPath()+"/"+ filename);
                    file.delete();
                }               }
            }
        }
        private void setMyInt(int value){
            int myInt = value;
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Pending);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf("Pending Uploads :"+myInt));
        }

}
```

Comment: please share full code

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` is returning `null`. Related: [Bitmap is returning null from BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442316/bitmap-is-returning-null-from-bitmapfactory-decodefilefilename)

Comment: @Radesh, I have added the full code

Comment: @MichaelDodd..so what should i add ?